# How to concatenate shortest paths from igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

How do I concatenate two shortest path responses from igraph so that they make one path? i.e.

```
set.seed(6857)
g <- sample_smallworld(1, 100, 5, 0.05) #Building a random graph
sp <- get.shortest.paths(g, 5, 70, output = "both")
sp1 <- get.shortest.paths(g, 70, 80, output = "both")
```

then something like:

`sp <- c(sp,sp1)`

So that I end up with the same formatting of sp and sp1 but have them joined together.

Additional: I need it so that the end of the first path is the beginning of the second path. So ideally there would be no replication when they concatenate. So if the vertices are `c(5  1 75 70, 70 75 80)` this would result in `c( 5  1 75 70 75 80)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are always easier if you name you name your vertices

```
set.seed(6857)
g <- sample_smallworld(1, 100, 5, 0.05) #Building a random graph
V(g)$name = 1:vcount(g)
sp <- get.shortest.paths(g, 5, 70, output = "both")
sp1 <- get.shortest.paths(g, 70, 80, output = "both")
```

Each element of the list can be joined together with `c` as long as they're from the same graph. Nodelists can be combined with other nodelists of the same graph and edge lists can be combined with other edgelists of the same graph

```
sp2 <- lapply(setNames(names(sp), names(sp)), function(x){
  temp <- c(sp[[x]][[1]], sp1[[x]][[1]]) 

  if(x == 'vpath'){
    newVPath <- temp$name %>%
      rle %>%
      .$values %>%
      as.character()

    return(V(g)[newVPath])
  }
  return(temp)
})
```

should give you:

```
$vpath
+ 6/100 vertices, named, from 94d5cf0:
[1] 5  1  75 70 75 80

$epath
+ 5/500 edges from 94d5cf0 (vertex names):
[1]  1-- 5  1--75 70--75 70--75 75--80

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

Comment: This is almost exactly right. Except because you use `unique()` if the same vertex comes up again later in the second sequence then it will be eliminated in addition to the duplicate in the middle. So by using `unique()` it's possible we lose vertices later on. If this could somehow work with `rle()` as described in @mysteRious 's solution then this would be perfect

Comment: ok, so then you'll need to name your vertices. just updated it

Comment: whoa, very nice

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using run length encoding `rle`:

```
> combined <- c(as.numeric(sp$vpath[[1]]),as.numeric(sp1$vpath[[1]]))
> combined
[1]  5  1 75 70 70 75 80

> x <- combined[cumsum(rle(as.character(combined))$lengths)]
> x
[1]  5  1 75 70 75 80
```